# ¿Por qué no siempre puedo ofrecer una recompensa a una pregunta?

Tags: soporte, recompensas

En algunas preguntas de otros usuarios me aparece la opción de iniciar una recompensa.

Por ejemplo:

- [Problema con acentos en "git rebase"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/194112/problema-con-acentos-en-git-rebase)

En otras no me aparece, por ejemplo:

- [COLOCAR FORMATO DE 12 HORAS AM- PM EN FULLCALENDAR CONFIGURACION ESPAÑOL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/308533/colocar-formato-de-12-horas-am-pm-en-fullcalendar-configuracion-espa%C3%91ol)

¿De qué depende esto?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No puedes ofrecer recompensa en la 2.ª porque es muy reciente, apenas publicada hace unos minutos.

De [¿Qué es una recompensa? ¿Cómo puedo iniciar una?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> Se puede iniciar una recompensa en una pregunta dos días después de ser publicada.

Tampoco podrías ofrecerla si la pregunta estuviera cerrada.

Dado que una pregunta con recompensa abierta no puede cerrarse, entiendo pues que ese margen de dos días se da por dos motivos:

- Para dar tiempo a que se cierre o mejore, si es necesario.
- Porque en los primeros minutos de vida de una pregunta ya recibe atención de forma *orgánica* al estar en la parte superior de la lista de nuevas preguntas.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la info!